# Adding integers in Range not working for negative numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, sum

I am trying to do this exercise:

> Write a program that asks the user for N and M and adds up the
>   integers between N and M using the formula

`SUM(N to M) = SUM( 1 to M ) - SUM( 1 to N-1 )`

I can get this to work for positive numbers but **not** negative numbers.

```
static int method2(int n, int m) {
        int sum = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            sum = sum + i;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            sum2 = sum2 + i;
        }
        System.out.println("sum: " + sum + ", sum2: " + sum2);

        return sum = sum - sum2;
    }
```

e.g.

1. using `n = -1`, `m = 1` returns `sum = 1`.
2. Using `n = -5`, `m = 5` returns `sum = 15`.
3. Using `n = 5`, `m = -5` returns `sum = -10`.
   These should all `return 0`.

e.g.

1. Using `n = -2`, `m = 3`, returns `sum = 6`.
2. Using `n = -2`, `m = 4`, returns `sum = 10`.

The problem is with `for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++)`, specifically `i <= n - 1` because when `n-1 <= 0` this will not run. I just can't think of a way around it.

Comment: This is a math problem.

Comment: Use `Math.abs(int)` method for negative number's range

Answer (score 1):

Your formula

```
SUM(N to M) = SUM( 1 to M ) - SUM( 1 to N-1 )
```

Doesn't really make sense for negative values. If you give that up you can make your program simpler. We very often start `for` loops at 0 or 1 but that doesn't have to be the case. You could instead start your loop at a n which might be negative:

```
   static int method2(int n, int m) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = n; i <= m; i++) {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: a negative case needs to be specified, and if m < n, you can just swap their values. This is just an example though and should be sufficient to work off of

Comment: Kind of... it will return 0 - which is how I would define the right answer for that case. You can see that by thinking through the first iteration

Comment: @SQLHacks returning `0` is not the solution. OP wants diff of sum no matter `+ve` or `-ve` `int`

Answer (score 0):

You could always check before if n < 0.

And then do another reverse loop for negative numbers.

e.g.

```
int sum = 0;
if(m < 0){
 for(int i = 0; i >= m; i--) {
  sum += i;
 }
} else {
 for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
  sum += i;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use that formula you could use instead of:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
```

the following code which changes the index either by 1 or by -1

```
for (int i = 1; i <= m; i+=(int)Math.signum(m-1+0.1)) {
```

(added 0.1 such that in case m is 1 the result is positive and not 0)

Ofc you should do the same for n.